# Best way to store continious simple data for productivity in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app that works with a device and I need to store my own made logs that include different IDs, angles, raw data and lots more, 20+ variables combined. Seems simple, but the latency is 13ms, so I'll be having around 20 insert requests per second.

Having tried implementing SQLite database did too much usage for the processor. I've done simple DatabaseAdapter that inserts data via contentValues.

What is the best way to ease the process:

1. Make native SQL commands avoiding usage of contentValues and other adapters?
2. Collect data in ArrayList \ Array and make insertion every second (don't know yet if array insertion is possible in SQL)?
3. Use different way to store data, i.e. open internal storage file stream and just put the logged data there and close the stream when activity is destroyed or paused?

Comment: Why do you have so many logs? 20 inserts a second seems like a lot. Can you not store the most recent log in memory and insert it into the database when the user closes the app?

Comment: Since the device will be used in medical field and it's "garage" made, I have to collect as many logs as possible, so I can later use all the data for further tasks

Comment: You could use an IntentService for the logging. This would open up doing the logging at a more relaxed pace over a longer period. Or maybe store all the logs in memory and then write it out to a file as json in the Intent service when the app closes.

Comment: It is possible to do a bulk insert: ContentValues[] bulkToInsert = new ContentValues[size];        this.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(contentUri,bulkToInsert);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insertion speed suffers from SQLite creating implicit transaction every time your try to insert (which is costly procedure, since it needs to get all sorts of locks on database). Bulk insert will certainly greatly improve insertion speed. That is: begin transaction -> do lots of inserts -> finish transaction.

However, in your particular case it might be better to just go off without using SQLite. Or at least, write raw data to file and then, when your field-trip is done, write it back to SQLite (so insertion is not real-time anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in a file, then at the end insert the data in one transaction in background.